# RoR - Routing Error after creating an event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a webapplication that can create new events and ruby binds them to a day. *So I have an belongs_to has_many relationship*

To create a new Event I made an own template:

**newform.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Event Optionen") %>

<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, "Titel" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description, "Beschreibung" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day_id, "Tag"%><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :day, @dates, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: false %>
  </div>
  <div class="field_small">
    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :start, :minute_step => 15 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field_small">
    <%= f.label :end, "Ende" %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :end, :minute_step => 15 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.hidden_field :day_id, :value => :day%>
    <%= f.submit "Event erstellen", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :admin_authenticate

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    lager  = Lager.find(params[:id])
    @dates = []
    for i in lager.start..lager.end
      @dates << i
    end

  end

  def edit
    @day = Day.find(params[:id]).date
  end

  def create
    event_params = params[:event]
    date         = Date.new event_params["start(1i)"].to_i, event_params["start(2i)"].to_i, event_params["start(3i)"].to_i
    start_time   = Time.new event_params["start(1i)"].to_i, event_params["start(2i)"].to_i, event_params["start(3i)"].to_i, event_params["start(4i)"].to_i, event_params["start(5i)"].to_i 
    end_time     = Time.new event_params["end(1i)"].to_i, event_params["end(2i)"].to_i, event_params["end(3i)"].to_i, event_params["end(4i)"].to_i, event_params["end(5i)"].to_i 
    title        = event_params[:title]
    description  = event_params[:description]
    day          = event_params[:day]
    day_id       = Day.find_by(date: "#{day}")

    @event = Event.new(start: start_time, end: end_time, title: title, description: description, day_id: day_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Event wurde erfolgreich erstellt.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end



  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

so after creating this event it should redirect to the root_path otherwise rendering back the **new.html.erb**.

I get every time this error :/ And i don't know how to handle with it.

[image: NoMethodError in Events#create]

Answer (score 1):

I think you get an error because you have not setup `@dates` in method `create`. I think you post the form with invalid params, `@event` can't be saved and you render `new` which use `@dates`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are trying for map method for nil object so try to find the object.I think for new Event `@dates` value will be nil ,so comment the line 
`<%= f.collection_select :day, @dates, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: false %>`
and reload page.